# How do you fix when my writing stops half way the A4 page and goes to next column

Tags: multicol

I began my document with

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[margin=0.1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\begin{small}
\begin{multicols}{3}
```

AND THEN I WROTE MY STUFF HERE AND FINISHED WITH

```
\end{multicols}
\end{small}
\end{document}
```

Then it looks like this as shown in the picture.

It doesn't go down the A4 page and it stops half way and goes to the next column.

How could I fix this?

[image]

Comment: if the full document isn't large enough to fill a full page, `multicol` will divide it up into even columns.  so what you have is the expected behavior.  the reason for this is that `multicol` supports switching between different numbers of columns on a single page (which the "basic" latex `twocolumn` doesn't), so each `\begin ... \end` is evened off individually.  you might take a look at the documentation -- `texdoc multicol` if you're working on a tex live installation.  by the way, welcome to the group.

Answer (score 2):

You can use starred version of `multicols`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,lipsum}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[margin=0.1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\begin{small}
\begin{multicols*}{3}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{multicols*}
\end{small}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Starred version does not balance columns.